# Get 403 error when create multiple vhost outside the XAMMP htdocs

Tags: apache, xampp, http-status-code-403

I know this is quite old problem, but i have no luck when trying to find the right solution. I have tried every possible configuration but still no luck. I'm working on PHP project using laravel. I got no problem at all when set up the laravel.labs as vhost INSIDE the htdocs. But when I move it into separated folder which is C:\vhosts i got this 403 error. The purpose of vhosts folder is to hold multiple vhost. The following are my configuration:

System:
windows 7 64-bit
XAMPP v 1.7.7
Apache/2.2.21
PHP: 5.3.8

**httpd.conf :**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot c:/vhosts/laravel_labs/public
  ServerName laravel.labs
</VirtualHost>
```

**c:\windows\system32\driver\etc\host**

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1                   laravel.labs
```

**.htaccess (inside the C:\vhosts\laravel_labs\public)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help to find something that i missed? any advice guys? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found The answer for this problem. I have to add some lines in httpd.conf

Something like this:

```
Alias /laravel_labs/public "C:/vhosts/laravel_labs/public/"
<Directory "C:/vhosts/laravel_labs/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

See the detail explanation here :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z250saioXIs

Answer (score 1):

Every time you add a new Alias or DocumentRoot, you need a <directory> section just like the one for your default DocumentRoot.  Depending on your release, this either has something like

```
Order deny,allow
```

or

```
require all granted
```

Comment: You're right. but it's not enough for my case. I found the solution on youtube, i post it below. thanks :)